# Slash and dash DDOS - what are they trying to do?

Tags: firewalls, ddos

I've noticed a curious flood pattern on some of my sites - bots trying to access the page ​"/-​/-​/-​/-​/-​/-​/-​/-​/-​/-​/" on the root domain - that's 11 slashes alternated by 10 dashes.

The thing with this is that it may be quite difficult for firewalls to catch it - Cloudflare and Wordfence are doing poorly (only working in certain conditions). Well, due to the nature of the string I couldn't even find anything on google.

For now I'm doing a redirect to a sort of honey-trap, but I'm nonetheless curious what it's trying to achieve and how it can better be rid of.

Comment: Something like this : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Full_Path_Disclosure

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [Full Path Disclosure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Full_Path_Disclosure) attack. This kind of attack allows the attacker to see the path to the webroot/file. e.g.: `/home/omg/htdocs/file/`. It keeps on adding slashes like `/////`  until it gets a file or anything interesting, and won't stop. It floods the site with slashes and special characters and the attacker *may* not know it but he is DDoSing the site. To stop this kind of attack you can use [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or use nginx and set heavy caching of /.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "it"? When you say "it searches", "it floods the site" and "until it gets a file"?